# At what time is `Timestamp::now` no longer undefined?

Tags: timestamp

The documentation of the `Timestamp` pallet states that the result of `Timestamp::now()` is undefined until `Timestamp::set` is called for the first time. Looking at the implementation details, you can see that `Timestamp::now()` returns zero otherwise. I would expect `Timestamp::now()` to be usable sometime during block #1.

When calling `Timestamp::now()` during `on_initialize` of a custom pallet on block #1, it returns zero, but during `on_finalize` it returns the correct time. It's my understanding that the time is set using an inherent extrinsic. Is there any guarantee where the time stamp is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timestamp::set` is indeed an inherent extrinsic as defined:

```rust
fn is_inherent(call: &Self::Call) -> bool {
    matches!(call, Call::set { .. })
}
```

Inherent extrinsics are guaranteed to execute before regular extrinsics, so you should have access to it during any normal extrinsic call during the first block.

Of course after it is set, then you will always have a value there, but it might be one block behind if you use it at the `on_initialize`.

Inherent extrinsic order should be defined by the order of the pallets, so you should also get access to it if you make sure `Timestamp` pallet is ordered before any other relevant pallet.